# Open express checkout in same window

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the js v4 express checkout (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-the-checkout-flow/), when pressing the "checkout with paypal" a new popup is opened with the checkout process in there.

Is there a way to open the checkout process in the same window without the popup?

Comment: Hi Mark, there isn't. The flow you're initiating is the incontext flow, you can however redirect them to a full hosted paypal page; not same window/page of course.

Comment: @GeekNinja how does Dell perform the checkout without the popup?  I'd like to do exactly what they do, which appears to redirect and then back after payment is confirmed.